# Credentials Missing with Passports.js

Tags: express, passport.js

In the signup process, I avoided the missing credentials with adding (see just below) while saving the user

```
newUser.firstName = req.body.firstName;
newUser.lastName = req.body.lastName;
```

But now when logging in I get the same error "missing credentials". Last time I added it while saving the user in the signup process but now I'm just loggin in...

What am I missing?

```
var passport = require('passport');
var User = require('../models/user');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

passport.use('local.signup', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
}, function(req, email, password, done) {
    req.checkBody('email', 'Invalid email').notEmpty().isEmail();
    req.checkBody('password', 'Invalid password').notEmpty().isLength({min: 6});
    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if (errors) {
        var messages = [];
        errors.forEach(function(error) {
            messages.push(error.msg);
        });
        return done(null, false, req.flash('error', messages));
    }

    User.findOne({
        'email': email
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        }
        if (user) {
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Email is already in use.'});
        }
        var newUser = new User();
        newUser.firstName = req.body.firstName;
        newUser.lastName = req.body.lastName;
        newUser.email = email;
        newUser.password = newUser.encryptPassword(password);
        newUser.save(function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            return done(null, newUser);
        });
    });
}));

passport.use('local.login', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
}, function(req, email, password, done) {
    req.checkBody('email', 'Invalid email').notEmpty().isEmail();
    req.checkBody('password', 'Invalid password').notEmpty();
    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if (errors) {
        var messages = [];
        errors.forEach(function(error) {
            messages.push(error.msg);
        });
        return done(null, false, req.flash('error', messages));
    }
    User.findOne({
        'email': email
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        }
        if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, {message: 'No user found.'});
        }
        if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Wrong password.'});
        }
        return done(null, user);
    });
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out... The problem was in the view. Had forgotten to include id and name on the signin form like I had in the signup form...